# Uncaught exception: undefined method `formatter' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I am faced with the error below when starting the rails server:

> Uncaught exception: undefined method `formatter' for nil:NilClass

There is another StackOverflow question, [NoMethodError on Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577501/nomethoderror-on-rails-server) which suggests to add `require './app'` to the `config.ru` file, however that solution did not work for me (it resulted in an error.)

I also tried adding in the `logger` gem to my gemfile, as I recently uninstalled all gems to resolve this issue.

[Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757144/your-bundle-is-locked-to-rake-12-0-0-but-that-version-could-not-be-found-in-a)

The exact console output is as follows:

```html
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:142:in `log_to_stdout'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
 /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/bin/rails:4:in `require'
 /home/daniel/Data/RubyOnRails/YoutubeBlog/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
Exiting
```

Config.ru

```html
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

I deleted the Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` which did not solve the problem. (Thanks for the suggestions).

Any help would be appreciated. :|

Comment: Can you post your `config.ru` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Gemfile.lock file and then run bundle install?

Comment: I have done that a million times already in an attempt to resolve dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle update`, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I noticed that the source code is deleted at config/enviroment.rb.

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize! <- this code is deleted
```

To fix the code, rails is running.

I think if this code is deleted, the logger isn't prepared and rails not started.